# Yes/No : Is the product of $I_2 \times I_2= I_2^2$ is principal ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra

This problem is  taken from Dummit and M. Foote  Books abstract algebra

let R be the  quadratics integer ring $\mathbb{Z} [\sqrt -5]$. Define the  ideal $I_2 = (2 ,1 + \sqrt -5)$

> Is  the product of  $I_2 \times I_2$ is principal ideal ?

## My attempt : i thinks  No

$2$ is irreducible in $R$, now take $2 = xy$ hence $x=2$ and $y=1$

$1+ \sqrt {-5} \in (2) \Rightarrow 1+\sqrt {-5}=2(m+n\sqrt {-5}) \Rightarrow m=\frac 12$ which is a contradiction because $m \in \Bbb Z$.

So $I_2$ is not  principal ideal

Now $I_2 \times I_2 = (2, 1+ \sqrt{-5}) (2, 1+ \sqrt{-5})= ( 4, 1 +5) = (4,6)$
in the  similar  way

$4$ is irreducible in $R$, now take $4 = xy$ hence $x=2$ and $y=2$

$1+ \sqrt {-5} \in (4) \Rightarrow 1+\sqrt {-5}=4(m+n\sqrt {-5}) \Rightarrow m=\frac 14$ which is a contradiction because $m \in \Bbb Z$.

So $I_2 \times I_2 = I_2^2$ is not   principal ideal

Is its true ?

Comment: Are you sure you've got the problem right? Are you perhaps trying to decide whether the product $I_2\cdot I_2$ of ideals is a principal ideal? The term "principal ideal domain" refers to entire *rings*, and you don't seem to be considering ideals as rings here.

Comment: Doesn't a ring have to contain a $1$ in order to be a domain? Is $I_2\times I_2$ even a ring? Is it the direct product here, or just the regular multiplication?

Comment: Hint: $2$ ramifies in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt{-5}]$ because $\operatorname{disc}(\Bbb Q(\sqrt{-5})) = -20$

Comment: @Wojowu i have  edits its

Comment: @Arthur  i mean$ I_2^2$

Comment: @ÍgjøgnumMeg im not getting  how $ -20$  come ?

Comment: You should revise how you got $I_2\times I_2=(4,1+\sqrt{-5})$, since this result is wrong.

Comment: @Wojowu check again  i have edits its

Comment: This is not quite how ideal multiplication works - if you multiply $(a,b)\cdot (c,d)$, you get $(ac,ad,bc,bd)$.

Comment: okss@Wojowu ya  but im confused     that  what type  of multiplication   works  in ideal ?

Comment: You should not use $\times$ to denote ideal product; in this context, it will almost certainly be (mis)understood as the cartesian product. The product of two ideals $I_1$ and $I_2$ is denoted by juxtaposition, $I_1I_2$, and is defined as the ideal *generated* by all products of the form $ab$ with $a\in I_1$ and $b\in I_2$; that is, the set of all expressions of the form $a_1b_1+\cdots + a_nb_n$, where $n$ is a nonnegative integer, $a_i\in I_1$, and $b_j\in I_2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, showing that $1 + \sqrt{-5} \notin (2)$ does not show that $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5})$ is not principal, it shows that $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5}) \ne (2)$. It is possible that there is some number $a + b\sqrt{-5}$ that is neither $2$, nor $1 + \sqrt{-5}$ such that $(2, 1 + \sqrt{-5}) = (a + b\sqrt{-5})$.

Likewise, the ideal $(4,6)$ is not equal to $(4)$ because $6 \notin (4)$, nor is it equal to $(6)$. However, $(4,6) = (2)$ because $2 = -1 \cdot 4 + 1 \cdot 6 \in (4,6)$, so $(2) \subseteq (4,6)$. And, $4, 6 \in (2)$ so $(4,6) \subseteq (2)$.

Remember that an ideal $(x,y)$ is the set $\{ax + by : a, b \in R\}$ so when you look for a generator, the generator should be in the set, so it should be of the form $ax + by$. But that generator does not need to be $x$ or $y$.

Likewise, when you multiply $(u,v) \cdot (x,y)$ you should be thinking about how each ideal is defined (linear combinations of its generators) and how the product of ideals is defined. So if you work it out:
\begin{align}
\{s \cdot t : s \in (u,v), t \in (x,y)\} &= \{s \cdot t : s = au + bv, t = cx + dy, a,b,c,d \in R\} \\
&= \{(au + bv)(cx + dy) : a,b,c,d \in R\} \\
&= \{ (ac) ux + (ad) uy + (bc)vx + (bd) vy : a,b,c,d \in R \}
\end{align}

So this is contained in the ideal $(ux,uy,vx,vy)$. Without too much effort you can show that $ux, uy, vx, vy \in (u,v) \cdot (x,y)$ so that in fact, $(u,v) \cdot (x,y) = (ux,uy,vx,vy)$.

Once you work out properly what $I_2 \cdot I_2$ is, you can show that $I_2 \cdot I_2 = (2)$ just like how I showed that $(4,6) = (2)$.

Comment: thanks  a lots @Trevor   Got it now